# Delete Few rows from Large table SQL Sever 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have this partitioned table( test_table )with 900,000,000 rows. Table has no keys. It has only 1 clustered index  on [ p_date  and email ]column.

Everyday one process runs from SP that tries to delete from this table.

```
Delete from test_table 
where userKey = 1
and convert(date, p_date) in (select distinct convert(date, p_date)
                                from    DB5.dbo.[test_table])
```

The sub query runs in other database but its super fast and returns today's date.

after this delete there is an insert statement also which inserts around 70,000 rows daily. This is faster.

This SP runs daily.

Delete takes super long.

When I check sysprocess, I see,

[image]

based on this info only I am able to find which db_id, which Filegroup and which table and which index it is working on.

Right now its working on file group Id = 16 of db_id =7.  We have 32 file groups.
**Is there anyway to speed up the performance for this delete here?**

This is powerful machine with 128 GB RAM. No other processes are running that time. Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason to use a subquery rather than the GETDATE() function?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the non-[sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) predicate on p_date to enable index seeks and partition elimination.

Try something like:

```
Delete from test_table 
where userKey = 1
and p_date >= @start and p_date < @end
option (recompile)
```

or

```
Delete from test_table 
where userKey = 1
and p_date >= @start and p_date < dateadd(day,1,@start)
option (recompile)
```

even if you have to run several such queries.

Comment: This could lead to parameter sniffing if `@start` and `@end` are different each day. Consider using `OPTION RECOMPILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is,

1. retrieve all the data to a temp table.
2. drop records from main table.
3. insert back the records from temp table to main table meeting the given date range.